# Maven structure and Java EE applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, ejb

How do you organize your Maven modules in a Java EE application? Currently what we do is have the following Maven modules under a parent POM:

- ear
- ejb
- ejb-api
- core

The `ejb` module contains only EJB classes, while the `core` module contains all other utility classes, including entities. The `ejb-api` is a lightweight module that contains local and remote interfaces, for inclusion in separate applications in needed. `ear` is used to make an EAR package and deploy it to application server.

How do you structure your application? I am particularly interested in where you store your utility classes and entity classes.

Comment: I liked the default netbeans directory structure `myapp-ejb, myapp-war etc` but not too keen on netbeans itself so pretty much coppied this and used ant with ivy which I personally found quicker to get to grips with then Maven. I have tried to keep utility classes etc reusable and uncoupled from my modest jee project and have those in a seperate 'library type' project which is included as you would with any library. I also package by name (or whatever this is called) where for example if I am working on entities for a company structure type model they would be packaged in `foo.company`

Comment: JEE apps often being web apps, it's common to have a `myapp-war` project containing the webapp-specific code. Might not apply to you. We don't separate ejb and ejb-api into their own modules; but it's a sensible idea and we probably should.

Comment: @Dario: You should organize your project with principle "1 module = 1 deliverable". Deliverable is WAR, EAR, JAR, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven has the concept of [archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/) that layout a pre-defined structure. I recommend the predefined archetypes from [org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes). They have archetypes from desktop applications to server side applications (j2ee 1.3 to Java EE 6).

Answer (score 1):

IDE's like Websphere RAD, Oracle JDeveloper usually create different projects for each.

With maven, you can just use one module and extract common code, interfaces into the client jar using maven-ejb-plugin, ok keep them separate. Only thing is project should use one and follow a consistent approach

hth

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
  <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
  <generateClient>true</generateClient>
  <clientIncludes>
    <clientInclude>com/foo/goo/**/model/**</clientInclude>
   <clientInclude>com/foo/goo/**/service/**</clientInclude>
  </clientIncludes>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```